# Detect Incoming Call Before Default Phone App

Tags: android, phone-call

Is it possible to detect incoming call before default phone application, and prevent to active default phone application in Android?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it may not exactly be possible according to this -> [Create a custom call handling Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257242/create-a-custom-call-handling-application).

Anyway more research may be required on your side to check if it can be. Multiple posts on Phone broadcast receiver can be used as reference.